# How to determine the number of reasonable combinations for n-char words

Tags: combinatorics

Lets consider the basic case: A-Z. for 4-char combinations there are $26^4$ values. But I don't care about most of these combinations because they are non-sense.  For example, any combination with no vowels or all vowels should not be in the final set.

How could I calculate the $n$-char combinations for words where the word must contain at least m-vowels?

Comment: Did you mean for $n$ to equal $n$?  That is, if you really want $n-$char word with $n-$vowels, then every character is a vowel.

Comment: Maybe first check a concrete case: how many 5-character words are there with 2 vowels? (Then, generalize).

Comment: Please use LaTeX markup in the future, if you don't mind!

Comment: edited. sorry for using n in 2 places.

Comment: Your definition still allows for all vowels, which you expressly state you don't want.

Answer (score 1):

$n=$ char word length

$k=$ number of vowels in word

$m=$ cardinality of the charset

As you want at least $n$ vowels

$$\sum_{i=k}^{n}{\binom{n}{i}5^i(m-5)^{n-i}}$$

Comment: And something with a binomial.

Comment: @AustinMohr Good point Austin.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that the character set consists of $v$ vowels and $c$ consonants, hence $v+c=:\ell$ letters in total. From this alphabet you can form $\ell^n$ strings of length $n$; but strings that do not contain at least $m$ vowels are forbidden. Now, given an $r$ between $0$ and $n$ inclusive you can form
$${n\choose r}v^r\,c^{n-r}$$ words of length $n$ containing exactly $r$ vowels and $n-r$ consonants. It follows that the total number $N$ of admissible words is given by 
$$N=\ell^n-\sum_{r=0}^{m-1} {n\choose r}v^r\,c^{n-r}\ .$$